# SharePoint Online Iterating through Document Libraries CSOM

Tags: powershell, listitem, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am trying to iterate though a document library and set each document/items whithin to inherit permissions (at the moment each doc/item is using unique permissions).

I am able to get the specific document library, however I cannot iterate though each of the items/documents within it. This is what I have so far:

```
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"

$webUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite" 
$username = "####"
$password = "####"
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$listname = "TestDoc";

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)

#variables
$web = $ctx.Web
$lists = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($lists)
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#print web URL
write-host `n "Web Url:" `n $web.Url

foreach ($list in $lists)
{

    if ($list.Title -eq "TestDoc")
    {
        #print list name if found
        write-host `n "Found the list:" `n $list.Title `n


            #attempting to iterate through items in the document library 
            foreach ($item2 in $list.Items)
            {
                #list the items/documents  in the document library
                write-host $item2.Title 
            }


    }
}
```

It is the foreach loop I am having trouble at the moment as I am not sure how to loop though each of the items/documents in the document library.

Any suggestions on the approach I should take would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting:

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1". At C:\Users\setup\Desktop\Test-BreakInheritence-Script-SPOnline\Permissions-Inh eritence.ps1:38 char:3 + $ctx.Load($items) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :

Was to do with the Load() method requiring additinal parameters passed into it. I think this is only required when dealing with lists/listItems. Did not spend too much time investigating the exact root cause, but I have reworked my solution and made it simpler:

```
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"

    $webUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite" 
    $username = "####"
    $password = "####"
    $securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $listname = "TestDoc"

    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)


    #get the List/DocLib and load it for use
    $listUpdate = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listname)
    $ctx.Load($listUpdate)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #CAML Query to get all items inclusing sub-folders
    $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $spQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
    $itemki = $listUpdate.GetItems($spQuery)
    $ctx.Load($itemki)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #iterating through the items and reseting permission inheritence
    for($j=0; $j -lt $itemki.Count; $j++)
    {
        $itemki[$j].ResetRoleInheritance()
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    }
```

This works like a charm now.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me build a script that modifies titles on documents in an SPO Document Library.